# ASP.NET MVC Return Custom Error to Login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am completely new to MVC so apologies if this is a simple question, but I have googled and cannot find an answer.

I am using ASP.NET identity with google provider and this works fine, However I want to check if that user exists in the database and only allow users with the userinfo on ExternalLoginCallback.

Here is my modified code for that function:

```
'
' GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
<AllowAnonymous>
Public Async Function ExternalLoginCallback(returnUrl As String) As Task(Of ActionResult)
    Dim loginInfo = Await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()
    If loginInfo Is Nothing Then
        Return RedirectToAction("Login")
    End If

    ' Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
    Dim result = Await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent := False)
    Select Case result
        Case SignInStatus.Success
            Return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl)
        Case SignInStatus.LockedOut
            Return View("Lockout")
        Case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification
            Return RedirectToAction("SendCode", New With {
                .ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                .RememberMe = False
            })
        Case Else

            'check first if the user has an account set up with this provider email.

            Dim uid = Await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginInfo.Email)
            If uid IsNot Nothing Then
                If uid.Id <> "" Then
                    Dim result1 = Await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(uid.Id, loginInfo.Login)
                    If result1.Succeeded Then
                        Await SignInManager.SignInAsync(uid, isPersistent:=False, rememberBrowser:=False)
                        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl
                        Return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl)
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            Dim errmsg As String = "You are not authorised to use this account"
            ModelState.AddModelError("", errmsg)
            Return RedirectToAction("Login")

                    End Select
End Function
```

This code works in that it redirects the user back to the login page, but I want to add a custom error as you can see from the code. The login view has a 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})

but my code I believe will only work for the current model "ExternalLoginConfirmation". How do I get this custom error on the log in view ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the message defined in `errmsg` when you redirect to the `Login()` method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - yes, you understand correctly.

Comment: Your redirecting to another view so `ModelState.AddModelError("", errmsg)` is pointless unless you return the same view (its disposed as soon as you redirect). One option is to add the message to `TempData` and then in the `Login()` method, read the value if it exists and add it to `ViewBag`, then in the view, display it inside a div element.

Comment: @StephenMuecke is right. Use ViewBag to display the error. [Read this on how to](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, - thank you both with the answer and the link it worked like a charm. Could you write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @TheUnknown - thank you both with the answer and the link it worked like a charm. Could you write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @grayson, I've long since forgotten VB so I'll leave it to you to add an answer :) - and since VB has been dropped from the latest version of MVC, you might want to consider switching to c#

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the wonderful quick responses of @StephenMuecke and @TheUnknown I worked this out.

I replaced

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", errmsg)
```

with

```
TempData("loginError") = errmsg
```

then in the Login Action, I added:

```
Dim errorresult = TempData("loginError")
    If errorresult IsNot Nothing Then
        If errorresult <> "" Then
            ViewBag.ErrorResult = errorresult
        End If
    End If
```

then in Login.vbhtml after the line:

```
@Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", New ExternalLoginListViewModel With {.ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl})
```

I added

```
<p class="text-danger">@ViewBag.ErrorResult</p>
```

It now works perfectly.